# Are all numbers representable as the sum or difference of the products of prime powers of a finite set of primes?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

If we take the first $k$ primes, are there always going to be natural numbers *not* representable as:

$$p_1^{a_1} p_2^{a_2} \cdots p_k^{a_k} \pm p_1^{a_1} p_2^{a_2} \cdots p_k^{a_k}\ ?$$

Assume non-negative $a_i$, in case that matters.

e.g. It seems to me as though no $2^a3^b \pm 2^c3^d=11^2$.

Comment: Without loss of generality, we can assume the number is not divisible by any of the $p_k$, and thus each prime will only appear in one of the summands.

Comment: @Trevor I don't know about the specific case you're asking about of $2^a3^b \pm 2^c3^d=11^2$. However, more generally, with the sum or difference of *any* $2$ prime powers, the abstract of [On integers not of the form $\pm p^a \pm q^b$](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2000-128-04/S0002-9939-99-05502-1/) starts with "In $1975$ F. Cohen and J.L. Selfridge found a $94$-digit positive integer which cannot be written as the sum or difference of two prime powers." It goes on to extend this to any $x$ satisfying a large congruence equation.

Comment: @Trevor More specifically with powers of $2$ and $3$, the arXiv paper [Representing integers as linear combinations of powers](https://arxiv.org/abs/1108.3737) has a summary of "At a conference in Debrecen in October $2010$ Nathanson announced some results concerning the arithmetic diameters of certain sets. He proposed some related results on the representation of integers by sums or differences of powers of $2$ and $3$. In this note we prove some results on this problem and the more general problem about the representation by linear combinations of powers of some fixed integers."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question seems to be that, for the first $k$ primes, there'll always be natural numbers which are *not* representable as

$$p_1^{a_1} p_2^{a_2} \cdots p_k^{a_k} \pm p_1^{b_1} p_2^{b_2} \cdots p_k^{b_k} \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

The journal [Archiv der Mathematik](https://link.springer.com/journal/13), published by SpringerLink since $1948$, has an article in June $2012$, Volume $98$, Issue $6$, pp $527$–$533$, with an introductory page at [Representing integers as linear combinations of power products](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00013-012-0380-4). It gives a preview, with the introduction starting with

> Let $P$ be a nonempty ﬁnite set of at least two prime numbers, and let $A$ be the set of positive integers that are products of powers of primes from $P$. Put $A_{\pm} = A \cup (−A)$. Then there does not exist an integer $k$ such that every positive integer can be represented as a sum of at most $k$ elements of $A_{\pm}$. This follows e.g., from Theorem $1$ of Jarden and Narkiewicz ...

This indicates that even a considerably more general result than what you asked about holds, i.e., not all positive integers can be represented by any fixed number of sums and/or differences of elements of a finite set of powers of primes.

Answer (score 1):

This is immediate from results on [$S$-unit equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-unit#S-unit_equation). Indeed, let $p_{k+1}$ be the next prime after $p_1,\dots,p_k$. Any solution to
$$p_1^{a_1}\dots p_k^{a_k}\pm p_1^{b_1}\dots p_k^{b_k}=p_{k+1}^c,$$
upon division by $p_{k+1}^c$, gives a different solution to the $S$-unit equation for $S=\{p_1,\dots,p_{k+1}\}$. General theory implies that there are only finitely many such solutions, hence in particular there are only finitely many $c$ for which a solution exists.

There are extensive tables which list all solutions of the $S$-unit equation for some small $S$, see for instance [here](https://www.math.u-bordeaux.fr/~bmatschke/data/#sunit). Looking at the fifth file and for solutions with radical $22,33,66$ (there are none for the former two, and for the latter there are a couple, but none involving $11^2$) we see that there indeed isn't a solution to $2^a3^b\pm 2^c3^d=11^2$.